# List which doesn't append in a for loop in pandas autocorrelation

Tags: python, list, append

I have a data Series which looks like this:

```
            Date         Open         High          Low    Adj Close    Change
4844  26/10/2020  3441.419922  3441.419922  3233.939941  3269.959961 -5.243488
4845  02/11/2020  3296.199951  3529.050049  3279.739990  3509.439941  6.076183
4846  09/11/2020  3583.040039  3645.989990  3511.909912  3585.149902  0.058850
4847  16/11/2020  3600.159912  3628.510010  3543.840088  3557.540039 -1.198015
4848  20/11/2020  3579.310059  3581.229980  3556.850098  3557.540039 -0.611940
```

I'm trying to create a new list which contains a autocorrelation coefficient for various lookback periods via a for loop. I've tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
Df = pd.read_csv("SP500 Weekly Data.csv", delimiter=",")
Df.fillna('')
Df['Change'] = ((Df['Adj Close'] - Df['Open']) / Df['Adj Close']*100)
   
for t in range(1,20):
    wk = []
    auto = Df['Change'].autocorr(t).astype(float)
    wk.append(auto)
print(wk)
```

but instead of getting a list of values, all I get from the print is the last value:

```
[0.002519726414980291]
```

At first I thought it was the type of value being returned [I got an ''numpy.float64' object is not iterable' error with .extend()], but .append() doesn't appear to be adding to the list with each loop.

Any help is appreciated, as well as any advice on the mistake I've made, so I can look out for it next time! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the wk list is being initialized empty every time, Hence you need to place it outside the loop like below for it to work.

```py
import pandas as pd
Df = pd.read_csv("SP500 Weekly Data.csv", delimiter=",")
Df.fillna('')
Df['Change'] = ((Df['Adj Close'] - Df['Open']) / Df['Adj Close']*100)

wk = []   
for t in range(1,20):
    auto = Df['Change'].autocorr(t).astype(float)
    wk.append(auto)
print(wk)
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out while I was eating, but didnt have a chance to update. Must've been tired and not thinking straight! Thanks

Comment: Good that you found out, but since your question is in open state it would be nice if you could vote up and mark my contibution as answer :)